# Error: Out of memory on composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, memory-limit

Run in cmd

```
$ php -d memory_limit=-1 -f composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 121896960) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in E:\Releases\test\vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\DependencyResolver\Rule.php on line 50
```

Test on OS:

- Ubuntu 13.04 **ok** *[PHP 5.4.24]*
- Windows 7 **ok** *[PHP 5.4.25 nts VC9 x86]*
- Windows XP **fail** *[PHP 5.4.25 nts VC9 x86]*

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I forgot to say that the script is running in a wrapper.
Directly into the console works, not working only in a wrapper

```
if (defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD')) {
    pclose(popen('start /b '.$command, 'r'));
} else {
    exec($command.' &');
}
```

Comment: just for the sake of testing, what does your php.ini say?

Comment: add info of php.ini. by the way 121896960 byte = 116,25 Mb

Comment: forgot to say about the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem, just up the memory limit in php.ini (for me, 1Go)

Comment: i set -1 as limit. it disabled the memory limit http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: if i set a limit of 1GB, the problem persists

Comment: @ghost404 Are you sure that you modified the correct `php.ini`? You need to modify the cli version.

Comment: @nietonfir absolutely sure that the changed. But it does not matter because the limit set in console http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php#example-364 I write in program `var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));` and see `string(2) "-1"`